# How to perform FTIR and RAMAN calculations using Quantum Espresso ​?

Tags: quantum-espresso

I am carrying out the calculations of a structure using Quantum Espresso, I have already calculated scf, nscf, dos, bands, charge density... Now I would like to do FTIR and RAMAN calculations. Can anyone give me a tip on how I should do this?

Comment: You can refer to this blog post https://blog.larrucea.eu/compute-ir-raman-spectra-qe/, it gives a simple example of the steps that you need to perform to do FTIR and RAMAN, basically you need to calculate the vibrational frequencies and extract the phonon information, afterwards, you can parse the dynamical matrix to get the properties you are looking for. You may also refer to this tool https://github.com/nguyen-group/QERaman described in this paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2023.108967, the paper has a full description of the steps that you need to perform.